# I am getting error. ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I am getting import error on executing below code in python 2.7 even after installing connector.

```
import MySQLdb
```

ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

Answer (score 0):

I might be able to help you.  I'm not sure what OS you're using, but I'm currently on Ubuntu, and the MySQLdb module was not natively installed, so I installed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-MySQLdb
```

After the install, I coded this small function to check if MySQLdb has been imported successfully in the file.  I do this using `sys.modules`.

```
import MySQLdb
import sys

def test_module_import():
    while True:
        print "Would you like to test if the module has been imported?" 
        retest = raw_input("Press [Y] to continue or [N] to exit ").lower()
        if retest == 'y':
            if 'MySQLdb' in sys.modules:
                print "Module imported!"
                continue
            else:
                print "Module NOT imported!"
                continue
        elif retest == 'n':
            sys.exit()
            break
        else:
            print "Not a valid command."
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_module_import()

    `
```

This confirmed for me that the module was in-fact being imported.  Try this out for yourself.  I'm sure you know this, but make sure that MySQLdb was correctly installed in Python's usable modules.